# how to check specific process (window task manager) is running or not using Windows Task Scheduler?

Tags: php, ruby, process, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

**I want to create a Windows Task Scheduler that will check whether rubyw.exe is running or not in window processes . if it is not running then Scheduler will run a C:/test.rb file and if it is running then do nothing.**

**how can i do it? in ruby and php**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! So you can take the approach as below using [`WMI`](http://rubyonwindows.blogspot.com/search/label/wmi) and [`WIN32OLE`](http://yard.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/WIN32OLE.html)

```
require 'win32ole'

wmi = WIN32OLE.connect("winmgmts://")
processes = wmi.ExecQuery("select * from win32_process")
ar = processes.each.with_object([]) {|i,a| a << i.name }
# => ["System Idle Process", "System", "smss.exe", "csrss.exe",...]
if ar.include? "rubyw.exe"
 #run a C:/test.rb file
else
 # do nothing
end
```

Comment: thanks , I will TRY IT, can you explain difference between rubyw.exe and ruby.exe?

Comment: @oecprashant You can put a separate question for that.. I am not aware of those.. sorry.. :)